# Add Fields and Methods to classes that inherit from same base without modifying base class

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

In my application i need to add some extra functionality to 3rd party controls.

An example would be TcxLabel and TcxDBLabel (from DevExpress).
Both inherit from the the same base class.

For those controls i would like to add some fields and methods.

The way i do it today:

```
TMycxLabel = class(TcxLabel)
private
  FMyField1: string;
  FMyField2: Integer;
public 
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

```
TMycxDBLabel = class(TcxDBLabel)
private
  FMyField1: string;
  FMyField2: Integer;
public 
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

So basically i have to write everything twice.

One way to achieve it would be modifying the base class those 2 controls inherit from. 
But that is not an option - the DevExpress classses / packages should not be modified.

Is there a way to add achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK there is no clean way to do this.

Comment: @MartynA Class helpers wouldn't allow me to declare new fields, only methods.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I was having a "senior moment".

Comment: Someone seems to be unhappy about the answers... But, what OP wants isn't doable.

Comment: Instead of adding these fields and method(s) to both label types, you could write a TcxLabelExt class which contained these fields and method(s) and add such a TcxLabelExt to both tMycx... types. Then you would have to write the extended functionality only once. You would have to handle the contained extension manually, but that is probably a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add achieve this?

No there is not. Any viable solution is going to be essentially equivalent to your current approach. Since you want the state associated with the instance, you realistically need it to be part of the instance. Which leads you to the solution that you have.

You could contemplate hijacking a field like `Tag` to store that state, but that would be wrong because `Tag` is reserved for use by the consumer of the type. Other plausible solutions might involve maintaining a separate list which mapped instance to this additional state. You could make that work but in my view it would be so unwieldy as to be worse than the alternative.

The most effective approach would be to add the fields to a common base class but you have ruled that out since it involves modifying third party code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, although it will serve only if you only need what is available in the base class.
For instance, if TcxDBLabel inherits from TcxLabel, you can add a method (loosely speaking) to both as long as you only use the TcxLabel part (fields, methods and properties) of the TcxDBLabel.

I'm referring to *typecasting*.

I should warn that the use of this practice is not consensual. Many developers regard *typecasting* as a bad practice, and I myself tend to use it only as last resort. However, I'll leave to you the philosophical discussion of weather you should or shouldn't use this.

So if you create a subclass like this:

```
THcxLabel = Class(TcxLabel)
private
  FMyField1: string;
  FMyField2: Integer;
public
  procedure DoSomething;
End;
```

You can then add this to any TcxLabel based class instance, like so:

```
THcxLabel(cxLabel1).DoSomething;
THcxLabel(cxDBLabel1).DoSomething;
```

Like I said, no specifics from TcxDBLabel will be available to you inside the DoSomething method, but you will be able to use the base class resources.

Answer (score 0):

Could you inherit once to a virtual class (which is "yours"), define the new fields there, then inherit the two new classes from there?

**Edit based on comments:**

well you could try smth like this.

In BOTH your inherited classes, just add one public data member, which is itself a class, where you define your own stuff... looks like:

```
TMycxLabel = class(TcxLabel)
public
  MyStuff: TMyStuff;
end;

TMyStuff = class()
private
  FMyField1: string;
  FMyField2: Integer;
public 
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

then call it like

```
cxLabel1.MyStuff.DoSomething();
```

I realize this doesn't completely answer your question, and doesn't work for several use cases (you can't access all attributes of TMycxLabel from MyStuff this way), but maybe you can avoid SOME double coding.

Comment: When you try to flesh out this idea with some code you'll realise that it is not viable.

Comment: Well I was confused about the "same base class" in the subject line. Apparently, he's inheriting from two base classes.

Comment: @Jur: yes, he is inheriting from the two classes mentioned. But these two derive from the same base class.

Comment: Your update is similar to what I would propose, although I would make it a property with proper getter and setter.